# Atom stylesheet

Tags: css, coffeescript, atom-editor

In atom (the text editor) there is a style sheet which you are able to tweak and I was wondering how to change the top bars color from this[image]

to this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't just a CSS fix. What you are showing in the top screenshot is a native macOS title bar, which is not something Atom has customizability options for (as far as I know).

In the Atom settings, under Core, you'll find a setting called "Title Bar". If you set it to `custom` or `custom-inset`, the title bar will become responsive to your theme's color. For example, if you set this to `custom` and then use the One Dark theme, the title bar will look similar to your example dark title bar.

Once you are in this mode, it is possible to further style the title bar using your own CSS, for example:

```css
.title-bar {
  background-color: orange;
}
```